# Debugger does not show all of the JS Files in React Native

Tags: react-native

Any ideas why this happens?

I already `watchman watch-del-all` but hasn't been successful. How do you clear the cache?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, my mistake. Apparently `react-native` does lazy loading. That means if you're not "importing" the actual file, then it won't be loaded to your debugger.